# libusb-1.0.so.0 for SLES 11

Tags: libusb, sles, sane

I would like to know if any of you can help me with the following problem.

I need to install the libusb-1.0.so.0 library on suse linux enterprise server 32 bits. I need the library because it is require by SANE software.

The operating system has some restriction, so i cannot run zypper or yast, But i can run rpm --nodeps -i to install rpm packages.

I also tried to download the libusb project and compile it, but the operating system does not have gcc installed on it.

I was wondering if any one has libusb-1.0.so.0 that works on SLES 32 bits or if any one has an ISO of SLES 32 bits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not tell the used service pack, yet.

Assuming that you're using the latest SP4, I'd recommend to heck out https://scc.suse.com/patches and search for the keyword „slessp4-libusb-1_0-12986“.

The pages provides you 5 patches. Select architecture "i586, i686" in the result list. You'll then get the compiled and source RPM of libusb-1_0.

You need to login first to download these packages. Please note that you also need to have a valid subscription. Since SLES 11 SP4 is out of general support, you probably need to have an LTSS subscription.